# Problem whit the use of Implicit function theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, functional-equations, jacobian, change-of-variable, implicit-function-theorem

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrqLb.png)

[image]

Hi guys!

I want to define for the part $a)$ $$x(u,v); \ \ y(u,v)$$ but in the problem change the order in the components. I calculate the Jacobian matrix and obtain an equation that I not comprhend because it remains in terms of the same function. I think that $a)$ and $b)$ are the same problem.

I appreciate any help and suggestions you can give me.